# MODx phpthumbof doesn't work in template

Tags: modx

I use phpthumbof in different parts of my website to resize images

It works perfectly in chunk using pdoresources from template

```
[[pdoResources?
  &parents=`2`
  &limit=`1`
  &depth=`2`
  &hideContainers=`1`
  &includeTVs=`post-main-image`
  &tpl=`main-post`
]]
```

here is code of chunk:

```
<img src="[[+tv.post-main-image:phpthumbof=`w=360&h=223&zc=1`]]">
```

but it doesn't work when I call it directly from template

```
[[*post-main-image:phpthumbof=`w=360&h=223&zc=1`]]
```

It shows image but doesn't affect on it's size or crop. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to try:

Is the output of the tv `post-main-image` set to text? (I'm assuming yes.)

In your template example, what happens when you add an ampersand `&` before `w=360`?

```
[[*post-main-image:phpthumbof=`&w=360&h=223&zc=1`]]
```

You can use phpThumbOf as a snippet instead of an output modifier:

```
[[!phpthumbof? &input=`[[+post-main-image]]` &options=`&w=360&h=223&zc=1`]]
```

(untested)

You can use **pThumb** instead (I have much better luck with it). https://github.com/rthrash/pThumb

Comment: output of the tv `post-main-image` is image
nothing happens in this case `[[*post-main-image:phpthumbof="&w=360&h=223&zc=1"]]` when using as snippet nothing happens, no image, the same with **pThumb**

Comment: thank, problem was in output, changed on text and it started to work. I was surprised because it worked perfectly calling from pderesources